# How can the binding energy per nucleon graph be useful if you can't compare "all" products with "all" reactants?

Tags: nuclear-physics, fusion, binding-energy

How can the binding energy per nucleon (BEN) graph be useful if one can't compare "all" products with "all" reactants?

Take the fission process of Uranium to Thorium:
$${}^{238}U \to {}^{4}He + {}^{234}Th $$

Other than Uranium's and Thorium's binding energy per nucleon, Helium's binding energy per nucleon is also important as helium is also one of the products but this usually is ignored, and generally when there is a decrease in the BEN graph one concludes that energy is released.

Furthermore, I was wondering how the process of Uranium fission releases more energy than the fusion of hydrogen to helium when based on the BEN graph the difference in biding energy per nucleon between Uranium and Thorium is much less than between Hydrogen and Helium.

PS: I am a high school student and would really appreciate a simplified explanation

Comment: Why is binding energy per nucleon even a worry here - the real point is an overall energy balance. But, you know that there are at least some reactions from splitting up U238 into daughter products that will result in an overall energy release.

Comment: For a particular reaction, you look at the Q value - the energy required or released. Go to ENSDF (say https://www.nndc.bnl.gov/ensdf/), enter 234, find the U238 alpha decay, and note that Q = 4269.7 keV - it is exothermic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When calculating the energy released by the $\alpha$ decay of ${}^{238}\text{U}$ you cannot ignore the binding energy of the alpha particle or you will get a spectacularly wrong result.

You can finding binding energies [on this web site](http://barwinski.net/isotopes/query_select.php). Using this data the calculation for the energy released in ${}^{238}U$ $\alpha$ decay is:

| Nucleus | BE per nucleon (/MeV) | No. nucleons | Total BE (/MeV) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| U-238 | 7.57015 | 238 | 1801.696 |
| Th-234 | 7.59688 | 234 | 1777.670 |
| He-4 | 7.07392 | 4 | 28.296 |

Then the energy released is the binding energy of the products minus the binding energy of the ${}^{238}\text{U}$:

$$ \Delta E = 1777.670 + 28.296 - 1801.696 = 4.270~\text{MeV} $$

Which reassuringly agrees with [the value given by Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uranium-238#Radium_series_(or_uranium_series)). If you ignored the binding energy of the helium nucleus your result would be wrong by $28.296$ MeV! If you'd like to give a link to the page where you saw the He binding energy apparently being ignored we can have a look at it and see what's wrong.

You ask about the hydrogen fusion process. If we take the commercially significant process $D + T \to He + n$ then the energies for this are:

| Nucleus | BE per nucleon (/MeV) | No. nucleons | Total BE (/MeV) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| D-2 | 1.11228 | 2 | 2.225 |
| T-3 | 2.82727 | 3 | 8.482 |
| He-4 | 7.07392 | 4 | 28.296 |

And again the energy released is the BE of the products minus the BE of the two initial nuclei so it's:

$$ \Delta E = 28.296 - (8.482 + 2.225) = 17.589~\text{MeV} $$

So the fusion releases more energy than the fission.

In a comment you ask about the reaction ${}^2D + {}^2D \to {}^3He + n$ and for this the energy is:

| Nucleus | BE per nucleon (/MeV) | No. nucleons | Total BE (/MeV) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| D-2 | 1.11228 | 2 | 2.225 |
| He-4 | 2.57269 | 3 | 7.718 |

$$ \Delta E = 7.718 - (2.225 + 2.225) = 3.268~\text{MeV} $$

and this is indeed less than the energy released in ${}^{238}U$ fission. However I don't think there is a way to see this just by looking at the binding energy per nucleon graph. You need to do the calculation. The trouble is that for the calculation we need the total energy, and that's the BE per nucleon multiplied by the number of nucleons.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation. It really did help me understand the concept of binding energy better. The fusion process that I mentioned in the question is one in which two H-2 atoms react and produce a He-3 atom and a neutron. My teacher used the binding energy per nucleon graph and explained that although the difference between Uranium and Thorium on the graph is much less than the difference between H-2 and H-3 the former releases more energy, completely ignoring the other products that these reactions produce and their binding energies (such as neutron and Helium). Why is this?

Comment: Furthermore, I was wondering why one can conclude that energy is released whenever observing a decrease in the BEN-graph. For example when from the slope between Uranium and Thorium we understand that energy is released completely ignoring the Helium atom which is on the other side of the graph.

Comment: @AuthenticMelody I've included the D + D ⟶ He-3 calculation in my answer.

Comment: I see... Thank you!!